# I don't understand why changing an image reference in a list leads to displaying said image

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm running a python code to manage images with tkinter but there is something I don't understand:

I have this "blankimage" :

```
imageblank = PhotoImage(file="blank.png")
```

A list of image references:

```
logos = [PhotoImage(file="%s.png" % filename) for filename in pool]
```

At some points I'm asking tkinter to display some images from logos, it runs fine.
But later when an event leads to replacing some of the displayed images in my "logos" list by "imageblank" with this line:

```
logos[allcards.index(Atest[index])] = imageblank   #(Atest and allcards are lists of names)
```

It will automatically display "blankimage" where the images it replace in the list where on my canvas.
I don't feel like I asked tkinter to display anything with this last line, should I?

thx

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Changing `logos` may not be itself an event, but the same event may trigger both updating `logos` *and* updating your canvas using the newly updated value of `logos.`.

Comment: No, it is not replaced by the *blankimage*, it is garbage collected because there is no variable storing the reference of the replaced image.  You can use other image to used as the *blankimage* and see whether this *blankimage* is shown when the image inside `logos` is replaced.